# Intersection of a hypersphere (4d) and a hyperplane

Tags: calculus

I have a problem to solve and I really am in over my head here. Just to get me started, if I have a four dimensional plane and a 4 dimensional sphere
$ax + by + cz + dw = k$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2 = R$, and they intersect, am I expecting a three dimensional sphere. 
In particular, what if I simply have x = r as the hyperplane, where r is less than R?

Comment: The typical problem here: Unfortunately, human brains cannot process 4D :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply the $4d$ sphere by $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)$ & rearrange it to give
\begin{eqnarray*}
(ax+by+cz+dw)^2+(bx-ay+dz-cw)^2+(cx-dy-az+bw)^2+(dx+cy-bz-aw)^2=R^2(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)
\end{eqnarray*}
Now substitute the equation for the plane & let
\begin{eqnarray*}
X=bx-ay+dz-cw \\
Y=cx-dy-az+bw\\
Z=dx+cy-bz-aw
\end{eqnarray*}
and $\rho^2 =R^2(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)-k^2$
\begin{eqnarray*}
X^2+Y^2+Z^2= \rho^2
\end{eqnarray*}
So the manifold of intersetion is indeed a $3d$ sphere.

Comment: That's good Donald? I see you mentioned manifold. This sounds like a very specific topic. If I wanted to actually get better at this kind of stuff, what resources are there? are there book on this stuff? Or did you just know how to do that because of a lot of experience in calculus?

Comment: Not only that, I cannot understand your mechanism behind the rearranging. How did you manage the rearanging of your original multiplication?

Comment: The normal to the plane is $(a,b,c,d)$ & the intersection will lie in this plane ... so we need to find three axes that are mutually perpendicular to this normal. $(b,-a,d,-c)$,$(c,-d,-a,b)$ & $(d,c,-b,-a)$ was an obvious guess.

Comment: OK, well now, I understand that bit now. Thankyou, but I still don't get what you have done with "Multiply the 4d sphere by $(a^2+B^2+c^2+d^2)$" bit. To me it looks like you have substituted the LHS of the hyperplane equation into a,b, c and d in the hypersphere equation and then on the RHS you have multiplied R by $(a^2+B^2+c^2+d^2)$". I'm not sayiing you're wrong, it's clearly above my comprehension to say whether it's wrong or not? i'm just interested how you got the result on the LHS so quickly if you multiplied $(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2)$" by $(a^2+B^2+c^2+^2)$".

Comment: See the formula in this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088530/eulers-identity-of-four-square-with-modulo ... multiplying by $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)$ was the obvious thing to do in order to arrive at $ax+by+cz+dw$.

Comment: Thanks, you have been a great help.